# Script with sleep() is slowing down server, causing Apache to crash

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache

I have a website that has messaging functionality between users. When a user is logged in, I use `jQuery.ajax()` to call a PHP script to check for new messages. To cut down on requests, my PHP script loops a call to the `check_new_messages()` function and if there are no new messages, I call `sleep(5)` inside the loop, so that it waits 5 seconds and then continues the loop. I check how long the script has been executing by using `microtime()` and if it exceeds 60 seconds, I return 0. The ajax will receive this value and then call the script again.

```
function check_message_queue($user) {
    $response = 0;
    $msgs = 0;
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    while (!$msgs = check_new_messages($user)) {
        sleep(5);
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        if ($time_end - $time_start >= 60)
            return $response;
    }

    // has new messages
    sleep(5);
    return $response;
}
```

My php.ini has `max_execution_time` set to 120.

At first everything works OK, but when I refresh the page there is about a 10 second delay and sometimes I'll get the PHP error "Max execution time of 30 seconds has been exceeded" followed by Apache crashing. My PHP max_execution_time is definitely set to 120 seconds, so I'm not sure what's going on.

I've never done anything like this before, so hopefully it's just some bad coding on my part.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var request_new_messages = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'messages/checkqueue',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        data: { id: 0 },
        complete: function() { request_new_messages(); },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { handle_error(); },
        success:
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (textStatus == "success") {
                    if (!isNaN(data)) {
                        var response = parseInt(data);
                        if (response > 0)
                            alert('You have ' + response + ' new messages.');
                    }
                }
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: Sleep on server side is evil imho, avoid that if you can

Comment: there is more than one config.ini to change the max execution time for php. In one of them you still have the max execution time set to 30 instead of 120, so you have to go and change it to 120. Also sleep is not the best way to do what you want here, sleep is synchronous and freezes whole server.

Comment: Ya know, I had a hunch sleep was freezing everything. Any idea how to accomplish this without sleep()?

Comment: Is there a particularly (strong) reason why you are using PHP and Ajax for instant messaging (IM)? (from your implementation, I believe you are going for an IM solution). If IM is the goal, XMPP is a better way to go. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272249/best-way-to-build-a-web-based-instant-messaging

Comment: It's basically a standard messaging system, but I know many users would use it like IM. The script above is to alert the user when they have a new message, or to update the messages if they receive a reply while reading the same message thread. I'm not familiar with XMPP. Is that something that can be used on a shared server?

Comment: So it appears that XMPP uses third part servers, e.g. talk.google.com. I'd rather have this all handled on my own server, but it sounds like PHP just isn't good at these types of things...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use PHP for that really. If you have an access to your server, i.e. it is not a share hosting or something like that, read about nodejs and socket.io. Besides that what is going on is that you are pausing the php every time once someone access it. Your script could be accessed several times per second. Imagine what will happen if you have 50 users. That could cause a crash of the apache. Can you please check the apache's logs and report the last few lines here (I mean before the crash).

Comment: The errors that are being logged are like this: `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\\Web\\dev\\application\\classes\\Messages.php on line 81, referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/site/messages`

Comment: Are you sure that you edit the right php.ini file? Can you please paste the path to the file which you change.

Comment: I edited the php.ini file referenced in phpinfo(). Checking phpinfo() shows the max_execution_time as 120, which is what I set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Why keep it executing on the server?

PHP and JS are not the best technologies to use for this type of problem but if you must use them, the following approach would be better:

Make an AJAX request every 60 seconds (or any other suitable interval you wish to use), check once and return the results.

There are plenty of questions/answers on the best approach for messaging systems on here. Example from the 'related' tab on the right:

[Best Way to Build a Web Based Instant Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272249/best-way-to-build-a-web-based-instant-messaging?lq=1)

Comment: The reason I wanted the polling to be server-side is many people will use the messaging like IM. 60 seconds is too long to send alerts. It would need to be more like 5 seconds.